# Find a substring with conditions with a regex

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, substring

I want to return `False` **only if** the substring has alphabet letter(s) both before AND after it:

e.g. given the target  `'at'`  and

```
strings = ['dad at home', 'eat apple', 'he never ate maple', 'because he hate it']
```

I'd like to return `[True, True, True, False]`.

I have now:

```
def foo(p,i):
    if p.findall(i):
        return True
    return False

pat = re.compile(r'\bat\b')
[foo(pat,i) for i in strings]
```

which returns `[True, False, False, False]`.

Comment: Try `(?<=[a-z])at(?=[a-z])` or `\Bat\B` which almost does the same.

Comment: Can you explain this `I want to return FALSE only if the substring has alphabet letter(s) both before AND after it:`, again?

Comment: You do not have to use `re.findall`, `re.search` is enough. Since you need to test for a match, `[^\W\d_]at[^\W\d_]` regex will do (it will even match any Unicode letter). If you only need to match ASCII, `[a-zA-Z]at[a-zA-Z]` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.search` instead of `re.findall` since you only test a string for 
a match.

If you only need to match ASCII, `[a-zA-Z]` on both sides of a word will work.

Use

```
import re
strs = ['dad at home', 'eat apple', 'he never ate maple', 'because he hate it']

def foo(p,i):
    return False if p.search(i) else True

word = 'at'
pat = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{}[a-zA-Z]'.format(word))
print([foo(pat,i) for i in strs])
# => [True, True, True, False]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1NqeEr)

If you plan to work with Unicode letters, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W\d_]`. In Python 3, `re.U` is used by default, in Python 2, you would need to add it.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! If the string is not too long `[a-zA-Z]` and `[^\W\d_]` should be similar in terms of speed right?

Comment: @BenLiu They are expanded by Python externally, so, `[a-zA-Z]` should be faster.

Comment: Just did! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex

```
def foo(p,i):
    if p.findall(i):
        return True
    return False
pat = re.compile(r'.*([\w]at[\w]).*')
out  = [not foo(pat,i) for i in strings]
# [True, True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a very very simple solution for your specific Problem.

```
def foo(text):
    for x in range(len(text)):
        if text[x] == 'a' and text[x+1] == 't':
            if text[x-1].isalnum() and text[x+2].isalnum():
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a readable one-line style solution using `re.search` and `map` functions:

```
import re

strings = ['dad at home', 'eat apple', 'he never ate maple', 'because he hate it']

s = list(map(lambda s: not re.search(r'[\w]at[\w]', s), strings))

print(s)   # [True, True, True, False]
```